# How to assign a video on a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, video

Hi, does anyone know how can I assign a video from my desktop to a variable? I know this is really easy but I cant find anything helpful online, please help.Thanks.

example:

```
var vid = '<source= myvid.mp4>';
```

I know this way is wrong, but whats the right way of declaring the video source ?

Comment: Could you clarify what do you need exactly?

Comment: i need to pass the source of the video in a variable like for image is : var img = '<img src ="myimg.jpe"/>' but what about videos ?

Comment: I don't think you can assign a video to a variable. You can assign a DOM element that contains the video to a a variable. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var video = document.createElement('video');
video.width = 150
video.height = 100
video.controls = true;

var source = document.createElement('source');
source.src = 'myvid.mp4';
source.type = 'video/mp4';

video.appendChild(source);
```